# Signign into gmail with tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, email, google

I would like to use Tor to bypass filtering/firewall rules that don't allow me to access gmail (rest assured it is not for malicious purposes). I've tried doing so in the past by gmail has an awful difficult time and is suspicious of the location I'm logging in from. Even with Javascipt allowed, it seems to not want to work and often hangs on the "loading".

Is there anything I can do to better use gmail with Tor? I don't really care about the anonymity aspect since I'm logging in as myself anyways. I have 2 factor authentication enabled in gmail.

Comment: You're probably better off just using a VPN for that purpose.

Comment: I've heard that Google will assume you are a hacker, and send a verification email, then you say that it was you logging in, and it doesn't bother you anymore..

Answer (score 3):

You can't do anything better because Tor is build for providing effective anonymity for everyone.

When you are using Gmail with Tor, Google see a bunch of logins from different places. Thats why Google is suspicious of the location you are logging in from. Tor is slow because your traffic is bouncing through volunteers' computers in various parts of the world.

As you don't want to be anonymous, I would recommend you to set up a VPN for your purpose. It would work faster than Tor.